# Why am I getting "Enter Parameter Value" when running my MS Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my query, I use the `IIF` function to assign either "Before" or "After" to a field named `BeforeOrAfter` using `AS`.

When I run this query, however, the "Enter Parameter Value" dialog appears, requesting a value for `BeforeOrAfter`. If I remove `BeforeOrAfter DESC` from the `ORDER BY` clause, I don't get the dialog.

**Here is the offending query:**

```
SELECT
    d.Scenario,
    e.Event,
    IIF(d.LogTime < e.Time, 'Before','After') AS BeforeOrAfter,
    d.HeartRate
FROM
    Data d INNER JOIN
    Events e ON d.Scenario = e.Scenario
WHERE
    e.Include = Yes
ORDER BY
    d.Scenario,
    e.Id,
    BeforeOrAfter DESC
```

**Question:** Why is my `AS BeforeOrAfter` not being recognized by the `ORDER BY` clause? Why does it ask me to enter a parameter value for "BeforeOrAfter" when I run this query?

**Note:** I tried using brackets, single quotes, double quotes, etc., but none of that made any difference.

Comment: Could you specify which Access version you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I beleive Access can't handle the alias feature, so you'll have to copy your IIF-block down into the Order By -clause. Or create a subquery (and then you might even find yourself forced to even not be able to use parantheses if your Access version isn't among the newest two or so).

Comment: SELECT
    d.Scenario,
    e.Event,
    IIF(d.LogTime < e.Time, 'Before','After') AS BeforeOrAfter,
    d.HeartRate
FROM
    Data d INNER JOIN
    Events e ON d.Scenario = e.Scenario
WHERE
    e.Include = Yes
ORDER BY
    d.Scenario,
    e.Id,
     IIF(d.LogTime < e.Time, 'Before','After') DESC

Comment: Thanks, Simon. This is my first time writing queries in Access. I'm quickly learning that it's quite different than SQL Server.

Comment: Why would you not expect a different database engine to have a different SQL dialect? For what it's worth, you might find some things easier if you set Access to use "SQL 92" mode, which changes a handful of things to be compatible with SQL Server's SQL dialect (the LIKE wildcards and the syntax for derived tables are the only ones I can think of).

Comment: @David, thanks. Like I said, first writing Access queries, so I didn't know what to expect. Another difference I just discovered: the concatenation operator is "&" rather than "+". I'll take a look at SQL 92.

Comment: The + operator is used for addition of numeric values, and propagates Nulls when used with non-numeric values. This is quite useful in an expression like Mid(("12"+LastName) & (", "+FirstName), 3).